# How to pass String value inside the url in jsp page for login validation

Tags: jsp

Hello I want to pass String value inside the url for login validation in jsp. Please help me. thanks in advance.

```
 <%

    String username=request.getParameter("username");
    String password=request.getParameter("password");
    out.println(username);
    out.println(password);

    %>
```

Comment: basic url call use '?' after url and append parameters 'x=y' and seperate multiple params with '&'

Comment: @rehan my url is--http://www.google.com/cgi-bin/login_app_gateway_v2.pl?action=login1&username=8&password=9

At the place of 8 i want username and at 9 password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a URL for example `www.yoursite.com/example.jsp?Parameter1=value1&Parameter2=value2`
and you want to get `value1` and `value2`
`<%= request.getParameter("Parameter1") %>` it returns `value1`
`<%= request.getParameter("Parameter2") %>` it returns `value2`